# Music Format Conversion C# or Java

Tags: java, c#, mp3, flac

I'm Trying to make a program to take my FLAC files off my desktop, convert them to mp3 and then put it on my phone, How can I compress the music into mp3?

Answer (score 2):

Use [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/):

> The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the
>   ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to
>   transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example
>   you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX
>   video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, you can convert a
>   WAV audio file to a MP3 or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and
>   transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing
>   their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers
>   and operations are supported by JAVE.